# How to adjust the weights or significance of individual features in Spark machine learning

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, naivebayes

Specifically I am using Naive Bayes with Spark 2.11.

Before you say "you should not do this" I do have strong reasons for considering this and want to experiment with how this could affect my results.

I'm training a Bayes model from an RDD of LabeledPoints:

```
        NaiveBayesModel bayesModel = NaiveBayes.train(trainingRDD.rdd());
```

Comment: I suspect that the right way to go about it is going to be derived from the "strong reasons". Can you say more about those reasons? What is the bigger picture here -- what is your overall goal?

Comment: I am trying to build a model based chart recommender system.  In my mind, some features have more relevance to the determination of the chart, such as "number of categories" or "number of measures" then other categories like "nulls in measures".  So I wanted to pretune it with these principles in mind.

Comment: OK, I understand the question now. I can think of 2 things. One is that you can include or exclude different variables and see which combination of variables works best (as evaluated, for example, by cross validation). Another is to look at the contribution of each variable to the overall score. I'll post another comment later about that.